# AWS: Is it possible to allow a Lambda function call an API secured by WAF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-waf

I have an API hosted on API Gateway secured by some WAF rules. One of the rules is the IP restriction rule, where I allow the API to get called only from certain IP ranges. Now, I have a Lambda function that should call this API, and of course if getting a Forbidden error. I know I can solve this if I put the Lambda inside a VPC and then add the VPC IPs to the WAF rule, however is it possible to make it works WITHOUT using the VPC?

Comment: For IP Address whitelisting, no.

Comment: Just as I thought. So there is no other way to do this, other than VPC, right?

Comment: Right, you are in control of IP Addresses from a VPC; though you would still want to use a Resource Policy w/ a statement that allows traffic from a specific VPC. If you are using a private api gateway, you will need to permit traffic from a VPC Endpoint.

Comment: Got it, thank you for your response :)